# Django Dumpdata file contains debug logs

Tags: python, django, logging, dumpdata

I'm dumping some data from my django app with the command `python manage.py dumpdata > db.json`

Unfortunately the `db.json` contains some startup logs in the first lines of the files.

The file looks like:

```
DEBUG $HOME=/home/web
DEBUG matplotlib data path /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
DEBUG loaded rc file /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
DEBUG matplotlib version 2.2.2
DEBUG interactive is False
DEBUG platform is linux
[{ ... then the json file ... }]
```

I guess it's coming from my logs configuration, but I couldn't figured it out.

Here is my logs config in `setting.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_simple': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'console_verbose': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console_simple', 'console_verbose'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console_simple', 'console_verbose'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are redirecting all output from the command to your file. Django's dumpdata command also takes an output parameter where to store the generated file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-output

Basically instead of `> file.json` use `--output file.json`.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to click the checkmark underneath the up/downvote buttons to mark my answer as accepted :-)